# Last value of array when object available

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the last value of `GDPAnn` from the array `Annual`. The code below works fine. But if `GDPAnn` is not available in the last value, it returns `undefined`. For example, I want
value `10251000` of GDPAnn from array `Annual2`.

```js
var Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":4.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"Value":4.8,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"Value":1,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

x = Annual.map((o) => o.GDPAnn).pop();
console.log(x);

var Annual2 = [{"Date":1998,"Value":4.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"Value":4.8,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"Value":1}]

y = Annual2.map((o) => o.GDPAnn).pop();
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Filter the array to only include items with a key `GDPAnn` before running your `.map()`

Comment: Thanks. Can you guide me as I am new to JS?

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see comment in code below - use `.filter()`

```js
var Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":4.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"Value":4.8,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"Value":1,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

x = Annual.map((o) => o.GDPAnn).pop();
console.log(x);

var Annual2 = [{"Date":1998,"Value":4.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"Value":4.8,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"Value":1}]

// Adding filter here to only include items with the GDPAnn key
y = Annual2.filter((o) => o.GDPAnn).map((o) => o.GDPAnn).pop();
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a simple workaround

```js
var Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":4.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"Value":4.8,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"Value":1,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

x = Annual.map((o) => o.GDPAnn).pop();
console.log(x);

var Annual2 = [{"Date":1998,"Value":4.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"Value":4.8,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"Value":1}]

y = Annual2.filter(o=> o.GDPAnn).map((o) => o.GDPAnn).pop();
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let y = Annual2.reduce((prev, curr) => curr.GDPAnn ? curr : prev).GDPAnn
```